# pass boolean variable as env, secret or configmap in k8s yaml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, yaml

We are working on creating a deployment yaml file for our Java spring-boot application to run on AKS.

I need a way to add a boolean variable as env, secret or configmap which I can pass the following application.properties

`azure.activedirectory.session-stateless=true`

to environment variable inside my pod like that

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: svc-deployment
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: image
        image: acr/image:tag
        env:
        - name: azure.activedirectory.session-stateless
          value: true
```

I read that yaml seems it can't parse the boolean values either with quote - "ture " -  or without. Is there any workaround?

Comment: So this isnt a `.properties` file, but `.yml`, yes? How are you reading the properties (probably in standard Spring way)? But how are you trying to read the 'value' property (i mean, how do you get it, like `env.value` or else)?

Comment: Just edit the original post

Comment: try converting your yaml to json or xml with [this](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv) or similar. The `value` is part of objects element in `env` array, so it's not the same as `azure.activedirectory.session-stateless=true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application.properties` can be configured by the `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` env variable

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: svc-deployment
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: image
        image: acr/image:tag
        env:
        - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
          value: '{"azure": {"activedirectory": {"session-stateless": true}}}'
```

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: Thank you. It's almost right. Just you need to add "\" as the following link. Please update the answer so I can approve it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_code_spring_application_json_code

Comment: I guess I don't need them because I am using single quotes

Answer (score 0):

To have an environment variable override a value in application.properties you have to declare the environment variable name in upper case using underscores as the separator.

In your case the name of the environment variable should be `AZURE_ACTIVEDIRECTORY_SESSIONSTATELESS`

See the [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) rules in the Spring Boot docs for further details.

Comment: how did you get an idea that this should be an environmental variable (i.e. from OS or OSes user)? I bet, the `env` as shorthand for environmental comes only from the yaml config.

Comment: Thanks. the problem is I need to pass boolean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround, nor would any make sense. Env vars themselves are inherently strings so the values must be too or it would just be converting it for you anyway.